# How should I structure the data schema of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have a chatroom system, and I want to use MongoDB as the backend database. The following are the entities:

- Room - a chatroom (room_id)
- User - a chatting user in chatroom (room_id, user_name)
- Msg - a message in chatroom (room_id, user_name, message)

For designing the schema, I have some ideas: First, 3 collections - room, user and msgs - and there is a parent reference in user and msg documents.

Another idea is to create collections for each room. Such as

- db.chatroom.victor

  - db.chatroom.victor.users
  - db.chatroom.victor.msgs
- db.chatroom.john

  - db.chatroom.john.users
  - db.chatroom.john.msgs
- db.chatroom.tom

  - db.chatroom.tom.users
  - db.chatroom.tom.msgs

...

I think if I can divide the documents into different collections, it would be much more efficient to query. Also, I can use capped collections to limit the count of messages in each room. However, I am not familiar with MongoDB. I'm not sure if there is any side effect to doing that, or is there any performance problem to create lots of collections? Is there any guideline for designing a MongoDB schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should always design your schema by answering 2 questions:

- what data should i store? (temporary/permanently)
- how will i access that data? (lots of reads on this, lots of writes on that, random rw here)

you don't want to embed high access rate data into document(like chat messages that are accessed by every user every second or so), it's better to have it as separate collection.

on the other hand - collection of users in chat room changes rather rarely - you can definitely embed that.

just design using common sense and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not want to embed messages inside of other documents.  They **need** to be stored as individual documents.

I say this because MongoDB allocates a certain amount of space for every document it writes. When it writes a document, it takes its current size and adds some empty space (padding) to the document so that if it is actually 1k large, it may become 1.5k large to leave space for the document to grow in size.

Chat messages will almost definitely each be larger than the allocated free space.  Multiple messages will absolutely be larger than the free space.

The problem is that when a document doesnt fit in its current location on disk\memory when you try to embed another document inside of it (via an update) the database must read that document from the disk\memory and rewrite the entire thing at the tail end of the data file.

This causes alot of disk activity that should otherwise not exist - that added I/O will destroy the performance of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Think about all of the use cases. What kind of queries do you want to execute?

- "Show me the rooms where a user is chatting". This won't work with the current schema and you have to add a list of rooms to the user or a in a separate collection to make it work.
- "Show me all the messages a user sent in all of the rooms". This, again, won't work.
- "Delete all the idle users from all the rooms". With the proposed schema you have to run this query on every room.users collection.

Also, do some approximation for the size of your collections. If you have 100 rooms with max 1000 users, that's 100000 entries for a collection where you store all these mappings. With an index on room and user that shouldn't be an issue, you don't need separate collections.

With 100 users you can even embed this to the room object as an array. Just make sure there is an index.